# PL/SQL invalid cursor error

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

So I really don't have any idea why my cursor isn't working. The select statement works fine, so I'm not sure why the SQL server is throwing the error. The For loop has an implicit open and close, so that shouldn't be the problem either. Any ideas?

```
DECLARE
   var_lname customer.c_last%TYPE;
   var_fname customer.c_first%TYPE;
   var_addr customer.c_address%TYPE;
   var_phone customer.c_dphone%TYPE;
   CURSOR expl_cursor IS SELECT c_last, c_first, c_address, c_dphone from customer;
   cust_record expl_cursor%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ClearWater Traders Mailing List');
   FOR cust_record IN expl_cursor
   LOOP
      FETCH expl_cursor INTO cust_record;
      var_lname := cust_record.c_last;
      var_fname := cust_record.c_first;
      var_addr := cust_record.c_address;
      var_phone := cust_record.c_dphone;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_lname || ' ' || var_fname || ' ' ||
      var_addr || ' ' || var_phone);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Here's the error:

**ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01001: invalid cur
ORA-06512: at line 15**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I solved this. Can't do a FETCH inside a for loop. Since the cursor is incremented automatically.

Comment: Yes. You were mixing the two ways to loop around a cursor result set. You either explicitly `open`/`fetch`/`close`, or use the implicit `for ... in ... loop` version. [More in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#BABDHAED).

Comment: I actually solved this like 10 seconds after I posted the question. Sometimes writing out the problem helps more than any answers you might get.